# Set server or workstation GC

Tags: garbage-collection, clr

How can I configure an application, or even an entire machine, to use either the server or workstation flavor of the CLR's garbage collection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/maoni/archive/2004/09/25/234273.aspx).

I recommend giving the entire series of blog posts a good read - very informative.

Comment: Thanks, that answers the question about how to do this on an application level. Can it be set for an entire machine?

Comment: I believe so - app.config is essentially a 'specialization' of the machine.config file which controls settings for the entire machine.  IIRC, it's located under %SYSTEM%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\vXXXX\<don't remember the rest>.
However, I would have to ask - are you sure you want to change this?

Comment: %SYSTEM%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.14322|v2.0.50727\CONFIG\Machine.config

Answer (score 0):

I should mention that I found there are two ways of handling this, either for the entire application using a .config file (application or machine), using the gcConcurrent and gcServer elements, or it can be done on a code block level using `GCSettings.LatencyMode`.